# How to process UDP data in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, udp

I have a service provider who is transmitting data thro' UDP. I want to establish a connection to them, receive & process data (will be with in the 30 sec limit/request)

Is it possible to get & process UDP data in appengine. I am looking for some simple example.

Comment: Socket is not supported, so i really doubt it. Any alternatives? like processing the udp as tcp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe it's possible. The [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html) on the GAE python runtime say this:

> An App Engine application cannot:
>
> - open a socket or access another host directly. An application can use the App Engine URL fetch service to make HTTP and HTTPS requests to other hosts on ports 80 and 443, respectively.

You would most likely use the `socket` module for UDP communication, which you can import on GAE, but does not contain any socket functionality (the module is empty).

Comment: Is it possible to have something like UDP over TCP. Or any other way to receive UDP data without using sockets. I am stuck up now as my dataprovider provides only udp

Comment: Not that I know of. How about writing a server (outside Google App Engine) that consumes the UDP communication, then sends that data as messages via HTTP to the GAE application?

Answer (score 3):

[Update](http://googleappengine.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/app-engine-177-released.html) for GAE 1.7.7:

> **Outbound sockets moved to Preview**
>
> Outbound sockets is now in preview
>   in this release for [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/overview) and [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview). With outbound sockets,
>   billing-enabled App Engine applications can now make outbound
>   connections with TCP or UDP sockets.

Note the word "*outbound*" above -- you still [cannot create a listen socket](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/overview#limitations-and-restrictions).

Answer (score 0):

You could run a separate agent on a cloud host like DigitalOcean or Amazon EC2 that proxies this protocol and makes itself available to Google App Engine via ordinary HTTP or web sockets.